# Tensorflow Federated with Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api, tensorflow-federated

I try to implement a demo of my object detection model that is trained with tensorflow federated.

Right now im a bit lost because I try to figure out how to modify the model_lib_v2 train_loop so that it inclused the tff client code. In the train_loop I alread have the optimizer and the model_fn but to build the tff [model from keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/from_keras_model) I also need a Keras loss function.

Furthermore I'm right now not sure if it is even possible to add TFF functions to the Object detection Api or if its more a simulation for basic Keras models.

Has anyone already tried to train a object detection model with TFF ?